# How to check return value of private methods in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to testing a private methods(not a action) of controller  with rspec

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def some_methods( var )
    if  var 
      return 1
    else 
      return 2
    end
  end

  def some_action
    var = true
    r = some_methods(var)
    r
  end
end
```

rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FooController do
   describe "GET index" do
      it "get get return value from some_methods" do
          @controller = TestController.new
          r =@controller.instance_eval{ some_action }  
          r.should eq 2
  end
end
```

This is my `rspec` code. However, the `r` is always 1 and I don't know how to pass paramater into `some_action`.
 How can I validate the real return values of `some_methods` using rspec way ? ( ex: `r.should be_nil` )

referenced but not work:

1. [Rspec, Rails: how to test private methods of controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271696/rspec-rails-how-to-test-private-methods-of-controllers)
2. [How to spec a private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154409/how-to-spec-a-private-method)

Comment: What did you try, and what about the referenced questions didn't work for you?

Comment: I try to write testing for the return value of `some_methods`. The referenced question 's solution can't determine the return value for `rspec`, ex: `r.should be_nil`

Comment: So you've written some RSpec code to test the return value of `some_methods`? Can you post that? Why are you specifically trying to test the value of the local variable `r`?

Comment: udpated. thanks.  I'm trying to test the return value of some_methods.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still a little confused. You shouldn't care about the return value of a controller **action**. Actions are supposed to render content, not return meaningful values. But I'll try to answer anyway.

If you're trying to make sure that `FooController#some_action` calls the private method `#some_methods` with a certain parameter, you can use `#should_receive`:

```
describe FooController do
  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'should get the return value from some_methods' do
      controller.should_receive(:some_methods).with(true).and_return(1)
      get :index
    end
  end
end
```

This example will fail if the controller never receives the message `:some_methods`, but it doesn't actually check the return value of the method `#some_action` (because that's almost never meaningful).

If you need to test the behavior of `#some_methods`, you should write separate tests for that using the techniques discussed in the articles you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got a few different issues going on here:

1. **Why is r always returning 1?** r is always 1 because you're calling `some_action` from insance_eval. `some_action` calls `some_methods(true)`, and `some_methods` returns 1 if true is passed in. With the code you've supplied, `some_action` will always return 1
2. I'm guessing these are just typo's, but your class name is `FooController` and the controller your testing in your rspec is `TestController`. Also, the `some_methods` function isn't marked as private.
3. **How to pass parameters**, you should be able to call `some_methods` directly from your instance_eval block and pass in a parameter like a normal function call:

   `r = @controller.instance_eval{ some_methods(false) }`

   `r.should eq 2`

Answer (score 0):

Check into log with print/puts statement or use debugger 'rails-debug' to check value at run-time .

> puts r = some_methods(var)

Comment: this is not solution, sorry. I think there is a `rspec` solution like `should be_nil` ... for example.

Comment: 'rspec solution like should be_nil' is the check that you are putting into the testcases . But if you want to see the value of private method in controller , then 
1) add puts/p/pp in controller and then check the test log.
2) use debugger , before method calling . Just take a look how debugger works .