# How can I write a test code for reject_body_scores(attributed) method?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :body_scores_attributes

  has_many :body_scores, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :body_scores, :reject_if => :reject_body_scores

  private
  def reject_body_scores(attributed)

    new_record? || attributed['date'].blank? || attributed['score'].blank?
  end

end
```

and

```
class BodyScore < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :horse_id, :score, :scoring_date
  belongs_to :horse

  validates :horse_id, :score, :scoring_date, :presence => true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
  describe "#reject_body_scores" do
    context "when record is new" do
      let(:horse) { build :horse }
      let(:options) { {} }
      it "reject body" do
        horse.send(:reject_body_scores, options).should be_true
      end
    end

    context "when date blank" do
      let(:horse) { create :horse }
      let(:options) { {} }
      it "reject body" do
        horse.send(:reject_body_scores, options).should be_true
      end
    end

    context "when score blank" do
      let(:horse) { create :horse }
      let(:options) { { "date" => Date.current } }
      it "reject body" do
        horse.send(:reject_body_scores, options).should be_true
      end
    end

    context "when date and score present" do
      let(:horse) { create :horse }
      let(:options) { { "date" => Date.current, "score" => 5 } }
      it "don't reject body" do
        horse.send(:reject_body_scores, options).should be_false
      end
    end
  end
```

You should cover all possible behaviors.

I've also used the trick using `object.send` for testing private methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154409/how-to-spec-a-private-method).

**upd**: 
Since you new to testing I'll add some description about testing.

I've use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) for creating new factories and use [short syntax](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) for that.

I've use [let](http://betterspecs.org/#let) to assign new variables instead of `before` block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new in writing test codes, so this has helped me a lot to understand better.